# What is the flow of actions when .setAdapter is called in a Custom ArrayList Adapter scenario?

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I am a bit confused by the concepts of a how the ArrayAdapter interacts with my ArrayList when attempting to populate a ListView in an activity.

Here's an example of a guide that is causing me a bit of confusion:
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

```
public class UsersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
    // View lookup cache
    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        TextView home;
    }

    public UsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> users) {
       super(context, R.layout.item_user, users);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       // Get the data item for this position

       >>>>>>> User user = getItem(position); <<<<<<<<<

       // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
       ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag
       if (convertView == null) {
          viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
          LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
          convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_user, parent, false);
          viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
          viewHolder.home = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvHome);
          convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
       } else {
           viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
       }
       // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
       viewHolder.name.setText(user.name);
       viewHolder.home.setText(user.hometown);
       // Return the completed view to render on screen
       return convertView;
   }
}
```

Let's say for example that I create an ArrayList and a new Adapter in my activity onCreate method.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ArrayList<User> myArray = new ArrayList<User>(); 
   User foobar = new User(); 
   myArray.add(foobar); // Adds my new user to the arrayList

   ArrayAdapter helperAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, myArray);

   ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.feed);
   lv.setAdapter(helperAdapter);
}
```

Once the method `setAdapter(helperAdapter)` is called how is my ArrayList queried for its object with the `getItem(position)` call in `getView()` method?

I don't see any reference to my ArrayList, I just see the object data being stored in a temporary `User` object, and I'm just a bit lost at how this could happen (I've attached a picture to try and help explain where I am lost)?

User.java

```
public class User {
public String name;
public String hometown;

public User(String name, String hometown) {
   this.name = name;
   this.hometown = hometown;
   }
 }
```

image
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the constructor to your `UsersAdapter` you will see that you are actually passing the `ArrayList<User> users` to the parent class constructor as the last parameter.

```
super(context, R.layout.item_user, users);
```

The `ArrayAdaper` keeps a reference to the list of users you passed in and uses it internally. If you look at what `getItem(...)` from `ArrayAdapter` is doing it is simply returning the item from the list at the specified index.

```
public T getItem(int position) {
    return mObjects.get(position); // mObjects references same ArrayList as users
}
```

Long story short it is the same as doing `users.get(position)` in this case.